# What is the font used on this California State Park Calaveras Big Trees information sign?

Tags: print-design, font-identification, sans-serif, signage

As per your rules for font identification, I've followed the requirements for font-identification.

**Here are the find-a-font site I've tried.**

- WhatTheFont! (Attempted)
- Identifont (Attempted)
- Serif Font Identification Guide (Not a Serif Font)
- What Font is (Attempted)
- Fontspring Matcherator (Attempted)
- Adobe Photoshop CC 2015.5+ Font Match (Attempted)
- FindMyFont (Attempted)

**Where the font is from**

The font is used on an information sign from Calaveras Big Trees California State Park. Here is an image along with cropped variations that I used on the identification sites.

**Other helpful information**

There is a possibility that it is hand-drawn, but from my analysis, it looks very consistent. Also, I would expect the State Park service to have a scalable way to produce signage.

Here are the resources I've searched through during my google-searches:

- Wikipedia entry: List of public signage typefaces
- CA State Park Brand Style Handbook Jan '07

Note: I would have posted the links, but I don't have enough reputation.

**Images**

Gallery with smaller crops of font: https://i.stack.imgur.com/t9zcO.jpg

[image: Calaveras Information Sign]

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: That is almost certainly a hand-painted sign, so you won't find that "font" anywhere. You could look for fonts that look like sign painter lettering, that might get you close-ish.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the others here that this looks like a hand painted sign. The letters forms are not exactly regular.

Anyhoo, FontSquirrel's Matcherator suggests a few fonts that are similar including New Era Casual Regular which is pretty close, and free.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That looks hand-painted.  I don't think you will have any luck finding that exact font, but there is some hope of you finding a similar font.

I would suggest searching for **Brush** or **Handwritten** fonts

I searched on [Google Fonts](https://fonts.google.com) and think that this one is pretty close:

**[Caveat Brush](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Caveat+Brush)**

[image]